# Hexadecimal change and save

Tags: php

I try to change the config file feeds.dat from the tool Feed Notifier, who can read rss.
http://www.feednotifier.com/

dynamically in Php. ( then I can zip in ).

I want to modify an url, by one other.

In this example, I do have the "default" url :
http://www.feednotifier.com/welcome.xml

If I try to str_replace it by one other, it fails ( Feed Notifier ).

So, I tryed with hexa class. Same problem.

Does anybody have an idea how to change the url ?

Answer (score 1):

As the file contains **binary** information, it has to be opened and written with binary flags.
like `fopen('feeds.dat', 'wb+');`

Do you know the file **format** for that `.dat` file? If you don't have a **manual**, you need to **reverse engineer** that and **extract** the information yourself.

It is possible that the url `http://www.feednotifier.com/welcome.xml` has it's length in binary format before, like
`31http://www.feednotifier.com/welcome.xml` so on changing that url, you need to change the **payload information** too. There might also be **checksums** inside of the file that must be changed. It all **depends** on the format the **developer decided to implement**.

Be **careful** with publishing data or config files to the internets, as they **may contain usernames and passwords** and some people are very good in extracting those information.

For PHP to work with datatypes in binaries, you need the `pack();` function and all its formatting codes: http://php.net/pack

To learn about datatypes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

A hint on how to reverse-engineer: Add an entry to the dat file via the feed notifier software (right click on tray, preferences or add feed). Then look into the file what did change. Add another feed and again look what has changed. Are there data types looking like timestamps? IDs? What strings are in there (mostly terminated with a `null-byte` or starting with a paylod), what numbers are in there, in which way they change. Does the program still work on changing (binary safe!) values?

Comment: No there is not length size ( Well, I dont see "31" or something like this ) and no manual ;/